# Whisper model (TypeError: expected np.ndarray (got FileStorage))

Tags: python, flask, openai-api, openai-whisper

`userInputtext =request.form['inputtext']` model = whisper.load_model("base.en")
`text_audio = model.transcribe(getfile, language='en',fp16=False)` result = text_audio["text"]

Solve this problem Thank you in advance

Comment: Hey Zubair,
You should format the code in a better way and give more details about the error you are seeing.

Comment: I am already change format the code but not get better result and still error

Answer (score 0):

Base.en is already an English model, you don't need to pass the language='en' parameter explicitly anymore.